# Increase every landscape image's size with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image, layout, width

I have a grid-based layout page with images that are either landscape or portrait (fixed width of `380px`). Every time an image is landscape I want to increase its size based on its width to `480px` (so the square-pixel area of all images is more equal).

I am not sure how to call for the images correctly. It should be applied to all `img`s that are on the page that is `<body class="blog">`.

And I am not sure how to redefine the width (that is generally defined by CSS) and how to make sure that the w/h ratio stays the same.

This is the code so far

```
var ArchiveImage = $(".blog img");
        if (ArchiveImage.width() > ArchiveImage.height()){
            //landscape
            ArchiveImage.width() = 480;
        } else if (ArchiveImage.width() < ArchiveImage.height()){
            //portrait
        } else {
            //square.
    }
```

Comment: First, you will probably have to loop through all your `img`'s. i.e. `$(".blog img").each(function(i, item){ //resize code });`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".blog img").each(function() {
    var max_width = 480;

    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();

    if (width > max_width) { // Only consider images wider than 480px
        if (width > height) {
          //landscape
          var newHeight = (max_width * height) / width;
          $(this).height(newHeight);
          $(this).width(max_width);
        } else if (width < height) {
          //portrait
        } else {
          //square.
        }
    }
});
```

I defined a variable to hold the maximum width: `max_width` because it's better practise to use a variable rather than a 'magic' number

The check around the entire statement is there so that only images wider than 480px are considered. You can remove this if you want smaller images to be made larger, although this would usually result in bad quality images.

This line calculates the height based on the ratio of the existing width/height, and the new width
`var newHeight = (max_width * height) / width`

As was pointed out by @zgood though, you can just use 'auto' for the height instead, so then you would not need to do the height calculation, ie:

```
$(this).height('auto');
$(this).width(max_width);
```

See it [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/gfys0xbu/):

Comment: for the height could you do `$(this).height = 'auto';` ?? I believe `auto` sets the height based on the width and the original images aspect ratio.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, that does something, but it somehow changes the size of *all* photos. I know, the code seems pretty strict on that, but no matter which photo, they all have the same – bigger – width.

Comment: The above code will also make images that are smaller than 480px wide bigger, is that what you mean? In that case you need to check the width first. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 1):

As you have all your images inside the `.blog` class, it will be easy to call all them with jQuery.

```
$('.blog').find('img').each(function(){
    //your code goes here
    if ($(this).width() > $(this).height()){
        //landscape
        $(this).height() = (480 * $(this).height() / $(this).width());
        $(this).css('width','480');
    } else if ($(this).width() < $(this).height()){
        //portrait
    } else {
        //square.
});
```

Just use `find()`, to search inside all the img's inside `.blog`. Then with `each()` apply the function for every img.

Hope it helped.

**EDIT**: Added simply rule of three to calculate the correct height. (Thanks mikeyq6)

Comment: You would still need to set the height if you do it this way. If there is a CSS rule for the height of the image, then this image would be stretched, as the width will have changed, but not the height.

Comment: I pasted the code into the `<head>` in a `<script>`tag where there is already some jQuery code, firing a masonry effect. And it breaks the masonry effect. The whole `<script>` tag with both looks like this: http://pastebin.com/y83w6DhU How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to change the img size befor that's masonry breaks. Try like this: http://pastebin.com/9kWn6wkf

Comment: It still breaks the masonry effect somehow... I think it must be something in the image-resize code, because I tried the code from the other answer and that one didn't break the masonry effect, but it somehow applied the resizing to all images, not just the landscape images.